# What if I don't know whether an html element will be img or video?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form with a file input. As each file is selected I add a preview of the image/video and a textarea for a caption.

In order to display the preview, I need either:

- a tag that can handle both image and video (I doubt this exists), or
- a client-side way to determine whether a file is an image or a video.

Comment: Couldn't you inspect the extension of the resource?

Comment: How are you receiving the data?

Comment: The question does not make it clear what is it that you are trying to do? Are you trying to generate a gallery from a dynamically received content (content can be audio or video)? Or are you trying to perform some action on a gallery which has already been generated?

Comment: That was kind of the point of the [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/object) element, although it requires configuration.

Comment: edited for specificity @sid-m

Comment: in that case, as @Carcigenicate suggested, you could simply check the extension of the selected file to see if it is a image or video.

Comment: "a tag that can handle both image and video (I doubt this exists)," Well, it does! :) That's IE you can use `<img dynsrc="video.mp4 src="img.jpg">` if you like both. (I wouldn't know if it is still supported on IE11 and forth).

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you want to detect and then do something based on the element   type, this jQuery should suffice.

```
var target = $('.media-element');

if ( target.is( "video" ) ) {
 do something
}

else if ( target.is('img')){
 do something else
}

else {return false;}
```